# The FeatureContext.Current static accessor cannot be used in multi-threaded execution

Tags: specflow

While running scenarios of two different feature files I am getting following error:
*Initialization method ITTCustomerScenarios.Features.ValidateTheJAMCMSKULicensingFeature.TestInitialize threw exception. TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: The FeatureContext.Current static accessor cannot be used in multi-threaded execution. Try injecting the feature context to the binding class. See http://go.specflow.org/doc-multithreaded for details..*

Though I am able to run scenarios of different features files from visual studio but not from mstest.
The command I am using for running sceanrios from command line using mstest is:
mstest /testcontainer:"test.dll" /category:mytest

test1.feature
@mytest
Scenario: Verify login
 Given I visit home page
 .....
 ......

test2.feature
@mytest
Scenario: Verify logout
 Given I visit home page
 .....
 ......

Please suggest me how to run scenarios of different feature files from command line.

Answer (score 1):

Found a link [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/572) which may be useful to some.
TLDR: **"The solution here is to explicitly regenerate all feature files."**

Comment: I had re-regenerated the files, but since I'm working in an environment with multiple branches and developers, new files were introduced that were generated with old Specflow version, and errors started happening.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the same problem by injecting the context in constructor like below. I guess this problem became after an update. Because `ScenarioContext.Current` is obsolete now.

```
    private readonly ScenarioContext Context;

    public WikipediaTitleValidationSteps(ScenarioContext catalogContext)
    {
        Context = catalogContext;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your specflow version and generator version to following one
SpecFlow Version:2.1.0.0(or latest)
SpecFlow Generator Version:2.0.0.0(or latest)

Regenerate all feature.cs files explicitly.

This will work for you. :)

Answer (score -2):

If you follow the link in the error message, you have a description how to  solve it.

Comment: Andreas, i tried the solution mentioned in that link, but couldn't succeeded in that. Do you know any other way to run scenarios of different feature files using mstest?

Comment: Ok, then I do not understand your question complete.  Could you add more details.
Which Visual Studio version are you using? Which SpecFlow version?
Does run all work in VS? What is the binding code where you get the exception? Why are you using mstest.exe and not the vstest.console.exe?

Comment: I've been reading those docs, and I'm not sure how to apply any of it to my situation.  I'm just trying to allow my `BeforeScenario` hook to look at `ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags`.  I feel like this shouldn't be that hard.